# counting elements in one list in another list

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, vectorization, nested-loops

df is this:

```
df <- data.frame(
           groups=I(list(c("a"), c("b","c", "d", "e","f"), c("g","h"), c("i")))
)
df$group_count <- 0
```

`people_codes` looks like this. eid is the id of the person, and `present_code` are the codes associated to that person.

If you want you can just copy and paste:

```
people_codes<-data.frame(
    eid=c(1,2,3,4,5,6, 7, 8, 9),
    present_code=I(list(c("g", "h"), c("a"), c("i"), c("g", "h"), c("a"), c("i", "a"), c("h"), c("f"), c("e"))))
```

I want to count the times where at least one element in `df$groups` is present in each person.

The expected output should be:

```
   groups                 group_count
    "a"                     3
    "b","c", "d", "e","f"   2
    "g","h"                 3
    "i"                     2
```

Basically I'm counting the number of people in each category. And you only need to at least match one code in the group to be considered as a count.

Using a nested loop this does the job:

```
for (row1 in 1:nrow(df)) {
  for (row2 in 1:nrow(people_codes)){
    if (any(people_codes[row2, "present_code"][[1]] %in% df[row1, "groups"][[1]])){
      df[row1, "group_count"] <- df[row1, "group_count"]+1
    }
  }
}
```

However this is super expensive, and I'm looking either to vectorize it or use grouping strategies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you need `unnest` + `left_join`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
    mutate(id = 1:n()) %>%
    unnest(groups) %>%
    left_join(
        unnest(people_codes, present_code),
        by = join_by(groups == present_code)
    ) %>%
    summarise(groups = list(groups), count = n_distinct(eid, na.rm = TRUE), .by = id) %>%
    select(-id)
```

which gives

```
# A tibble: 4 × 2
  groups    count
  <list>    <int>
1 <chr [3]>     3
2 <chr [5]>     2
3 <chr [5]>     3
4 <chr [2]>     2
```

---

If you want to save all unique info, you can use `list(unique(na.omit(eid)))`, i.e.,

```
df %>%
    mutate(id = 1:n()) %>%
    unnest(groups) %>%
    left_join(
        unnest(people_codes, present_code),
        by = join_by(groups == present_code)
    ) %>%
    summarise(
        groups = list(groups),
        count = n_distinct(eid, na.rm = TRUE),
        info = list(unique(na.omit(eid))),
        .by = id
    ) %>%
    select(-id) %>%
    as.data.frame()
```

which gives

```
         groups count    info
1       a, a, a     3 2, 5, 6
2 b, c, d, e, f     2    9, 8
3 g, g, h, h, h     3 1, 4, 7
4          i, i     2    3, 6
```

Comment: Thank you! However the groups list is wrong. Some entries are repeated. I think the problem is in groups = list(groups).

Comment: would list(unique(groups)) do the job?

Comment: Also, is it possible to save the info about all unique eid? maybe adding people = list(unique(eid))?

Comment: @Caterina yes, of course you can do like that. please see my update

Answer (score 2):

This is still a double loop, hidden behind `sapply`, but it might be a bit more straightforward:

```
sapply(df$groups, \(x) 
    sum(sapply(people_codes$present_code, \(y) any(x %in% y))) )
#[1] 3 2 3 2
```

Comment: This also does the job, but it is almost as slow as the nested loop.

Comment: @Caterina - that doesn't surprise me. I imagine the join as per Thomas's answer will be a lot more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another idea. First, I used unnest() to deal with the list variable. Then, I decided to used case_when(), which requires a bit of writing. (If you have groups more this idea may not be ideal.) This part is creating a grouping variable. If I am not mistaken, you consider one entry of one person in each group; eid1 has two entries in the gh group at this moment. Hence, I decided to used distinct(). Finally, counting the frequency for each group using count().

```
unnest(people_codes, present_code) %>% 
  mutate(groups = case_when(present_code == "a" ~ "a",
                            present_code %in% letters[2:6] ~ paste0(letters[2:6], collapse = ""),
                            present_code %in% letters[7:8] ~ paste0(letters[7:8], collapse = ""),
                            present_code == "i" ~ "i")) %>% 
distinct(eid, groups) %>% 
count(groups)

#  groups     n
#  <chr>  <int>
#1 a          3
#2 bcdef      2
#3 gh         3
#4 i          2
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `outer`.

```
> f <- \(x, y) any(x %in% y)
> rowSums(outer(df$groups, people_codes$present_code, Vectorize(f)))
[1] 3 2 3 2
```

`matrixStats::rowSums2` might be faster.

```
> matrixStats::rowSums2(outer(df$groups, people_codes$present_code, Vectorize(f)))
[1] 3 2 3 2
```